# Stuck low-feerate transaction after forced closed channel

Tags: lightning-network, unconfirmed-transactions, ln-closing-channels, lndhub

Someone cooperatively closed a channel with me, then forced closed it later.  It has not confirmed. In fact, it is not even showing up in mempool, which says "waiting for transaction". I'm guessing, the feerate is very low in this high on chain feerate environment right now. So, how long will I be waiting to get my funds? I can’t bump the fee because they closed it. The other party doesn’t know how to bump the fee or doesn’t want to, even if I pay for it. If the transaction never confirms, what happens to my satoshis? It’s currently worth $2000. The situation is very frustrating to me.